# Why my $.ajax() doesn't work in firefox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, post

Hi I have a code for posting on my site and it works perfectly in safari, but in firefox not. I don't know the problem, because the code is very simple ...
Here the code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="mmm..." class="bar" name="txt" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="map" />
<button onclick="post('2')">send</button>
<div id="prueba"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    function post(id) {
        var txtvalue = document.getElementsByName('txt')[0].value;
        if (document.getElementsByName('map')[0]) {
            var mapv = document.getElementsByName('map')[0].value;
        } else {
            var mapv = "";
        }
        $('#prueba').html('txt:' + txtvalue + '<br>map:' + mapv);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://m2s.es/app/api/connect/chat.php",
            data: {
                txt: txtvalue,
                map: mapv,
                id: id
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log('connecting...')
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log('procesing...')
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error(textStatus);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

For that the PHP process the post, you must be logged in to the http://m2s.es/app, but still in firefox will give error in the console (with login or not) and not as in safari, if you don't login, it will say in the console: 'not Login'

Comment: What is the error message in the console that Firefox gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may caused by crossdomain, if you didn't run this js code under http://m2s.es/ , it will cause the crossdomain problem, and you will get error in ajax.

Comment: this seems like wild speculation to me.

Comment: And, why in Safari works fine? Is there any way to make it work without being in the domain?

Comment: @user3228573 this may different from browser to browser. jsonp is a way to solve the crossdomain problem

Comment: Has you got other solution?

Comment: If it is cross domain, there is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score 1):

Well the one issue I see is not related to the bug is

```
if (document.getElementsByName('map')[0]) {
```

if the length is zero, than you will have an error

```
var map = document.getElementsByName('map');
var mapv = map.length ? map[0].value : "";
```

or just use jQuery

```
var mapv = $('[name="map"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

When I logged on to your site I got the following in firefox, using firebug:

TypeError: input is null : appnew.js (line 40)

```
39 var input = document.getElementById('input');
40 input.onkeyup = function () {
```

On line 39 you are trying to get an element with id=input, but since you dont have any element with id input line 40 gives the error.